# Array Redim Preserve transposing columns into multiple rows error Subscript out of Range Error

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am new to this forum and also have a bit of knowledge in VBA. I am having trouble figuring out the error behind the code that I am currently using. I am trying to convert columns into multiple rows. Sample data below:
[Sample Data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtmHE.png)

Code I used for the data above:

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim wsThis As Worksheet, wsThat As Worksheet
    Dim vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
    Dim r As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    Dim c As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

    Set wsThis = Sheet5: Set wsThat = Sheet8

    vdblast = wsThis.Range("A" & wsThis.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    vDB = wsThis.Range("A1:CC" & vdblast)
    vDB = wsThis.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    c = UBound(vDB, 2)

    n = 1
    For i = 2 To r
        For j = 8 To c
            If vDB(i, j) <> "" Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 9, 1 To n)
                For k = 1 To 8
                    vR(k, n) = vDB(i, k)
                Next k
            End If
            vR(9, n) = vDB(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    
    With wsThat
        .UsedRange.Clear
        .Range("a1").Resize(1, 8) = wsThis.Range("a1").Resize(1, 9).Value
        .Range("h1").Resize(1, 1) = Array("Activity Template")
        .Range("a2").Resize(n, 8) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    End With

End Sub
```

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: " I am having trouble figuring out the error" - what error ?

Comment: Hi Tim, Subscript out range error on this part of code
vR(9, n) = vDB(i, j)
I am not sure what is wrong with my code.

Comment: When you get the error, what are the values of `n`, `i` and `j`? (look in the Locals window), and what are the dimensions of `vR` and `vDB`? (also from the locals window, first line for each of those arrays).

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfeld, the values are
n = 1;
i = 2;
j = 8;
vR = Variant();
VDB = Variant/Variant(1 to 86, 1 to 81)

Comment: Likely `vDB(2,8) = ""`  So, when you get to the error line, `vR` is still undimensioned, hence your error. Check `vDB(2,8)` by expanding the locals window at the time of your error, and inspecting that element.  If that is the case, check to see how you can properly assign your desired range to `vDB`

Comment: Just looked at your screen shot, and not sure if you are interested, but in `Power Query` this would be a simple `unpivot`.  `Unpivot` the `Activity` columns; then delete the Value column and you have your result.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks. It seems that I don't have any condition to handle blank cells in my vDB array. I don't know what code to use for my else statement to ReDim Preserve blank cells. Please help me.

Comment: I suppose you could move `vR(9, n) = vDB(i, j)` to inside the `If` clause, so it won't execute if `vDB(i,j)` is empty.  But honestly, it took about 2 seconds to create the Power Query to do the unpivot.  If that's what you need, I'd look there.

Comment: @RonRosenfield thanks for your suggestions. I wanted to use Power Query but the end user for this doesn't know how to install Power Query. Anyway, I'll try to understand arrays a bit more and come back to this forum if I have any more questions. Thanks for your help, I'd like to upvote but I have low reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub test()
    Const FIXED_COLS As Long = 7
    
    Dim wsThis As Worksheet, wsThat As Worksheet
    Dim vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
    Dim rws As Long, cols As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim k As Long, n As Long

    Set wsThis = Sheet5
    Set wsThat = Sheet8

    vDB = wsThis.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    rws = UBound(vDB, 1)
    cols = UBound(vDB, 2)

    'size output array to max size needed: skip resizing
    ReDim vR(1 To rws * (cols - FIXED_COLS), 1 To FIXED_COLS + 1)
    
    'copy the headers
    For c = 1 To FIXED_COLS
        vR(1, c) = vDB(1, c)
    Next c
    vR(1, FIXED_COLS + 1) = "Activity Template"
    
    'copy the data
    n = 1
    For r = 2 To rws
        For c = FIXED_COLS + 1 To cols
            If Len(vDB(r, c)) > 0 Then
                n = n + 1
                For k = 1 To FIXED_COLS
                    vR(n, k) = vDB(r, k)
                Next k
                vR(n, FIXED_COLS + 1) = vDB(1, c)
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    
    With wsThat
        .UsedRange.Clear
        'only write the used part of the output array
        .Range("a1").Resize(n, FIXED_COLS + 1) = vR
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks your a genius!!! I am glad I joined this forum. I still have long ways to go to better understand VBA. But I'll definitely learn how you did this. I hope I can someday learn this. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

The array vDB contains all rows and cols of your Sheet5, you probably have less than 8 columns (value of k 1 to 8).

For debuging your scripts, you can use F8 to go step by step trough your code, as the yellow marker will advance, when you go over your vars with your mouse you'll be able to see their value at that moment of your script.

Comment: Thanks @Ceci, I just don't know what is the error of the code that I am using, it returns "Subscript out of range" in the line `vR(9,n) = vDB(i,j)` even if I change the value of 9 to any number it still returns the error.